# Qual modo correto de aplicar Lightbox pra cada link descritivo e limpar

Tags: javascript, html, css, div

Estou com um pequeno contra-tempo. Necessito da ajuda de vocês pra variar.

Estou praticando em um projeto pessoal, o efeito *Light Box* e se possível gostaria de ouvir o *caro(a)s colega*. Seja apontando erros ou alterações para fins didáticos, critícas construtivas sempre será bem-vindos!

## Código

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.ativo) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.ativo {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.escurecer{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    z-index:1001;
    opacity:.80;
}

#sobre {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 37%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#contato {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 37%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="ativo" href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato" onclick="document.getElementById('contato').style.display='block';document.getElementById('escurecer').style.display='block'">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre" onclick="document.getElementById('sobre').style.display='block';document.getElementById('escurecer').style.display='block'">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="sobre" class="box"><h4>Sobre nós</h4><hr><br>

  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>

</div>

<div id="contato" class="box"><h4>Fale conosco</h4><hr><br>

 <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>

</div>

        <div id="escurecer" class="escurecer" onclick="document.getElementById('escurecer').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sobre').style.display='none';document.getElementById('contato').style.display='none';"></div>
```

## Print

[image: Print Screen - LightBox Sobre]

[image: Print Screen - LightBox Contato]

> **Problema** - Acho que poderia melhorar o modo funcional do trecho:

```
<div id="escurecer" class="escurecer" onclick="document.getElementById('escurecer').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sobre').style.display='none';document.getElementById('contato').style.display='none';"></div>
```

---

```
document.getElementById('sobre').style.display='none';     

document.getElementById('contato').style.display='none';"
```

Isso é para limpar/ocultar as `divs` flutuantes.

Queria saber se alguém me propõe algo.. vamos dizer mais bonito em relação a esta repetição de linhas.

**Lembrete** - Todo o código fonte apresentado aqui, funciona redondinho. Só vim colher melhorias ou alternativas no determinado trecho. No qual acho esta muito amador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem varias formas de fazer isso, um exemplo basico para deixar seu codigo mais limpo é

```js
let classe = document.getElementsByClassName('link')
let escurecer = document.getElementById('escurecer')

escurecer.onclick = function(){
   escurecer.style.display = 'none'
   document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'none'
}

for(let i = 0; i < classe.length; i++){
  classe[i].onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'block'
    escurecer.style.display = 'block'
    
    let attr = classe[i].getAttribute("href")
    // Coloco o conteudo
    
    if(attr == '#contato'){
      document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = '<h1>Contato</h1>'
    }else{
        
      document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = '<h1>Sobre</h1>'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.ativo) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.ativo {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.escurecer{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    z-index:1001;
    opacity:.80;
}

#modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 37%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#contato {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 37%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="link ativo" href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="modal" class="box"></div>
<div id="escurecer" class="escurecer"></div>
```

Lembrando que é só um exemplo de fazer algo generico, você pode melhorar o codigo pra ficar melhor ainda.

Comment: Fiz uma edição para fechar a modal ao clicar na `div` escurecer

Comment: Compreendo o que você quiz me dizer com - "Existem varias formas de fazer isso, um exemplo basico para deixar seu codigo mais limpo é... avaliar uma expressão aritmética utilizando a função. `let`". Bom, eu interpretei dessa forma teu código. Ficou legal!

Comment: Me deparei com obstáculo, que se resume sobre o código do script. Ou seja, não pude usá-lo dentre as *tags* `<head></head>`.  Mas sim, dentre as *tags* `</body>` e `</html>`. Assim o documento HTML, ganha tempo para que o `load` dos elementos em si, seja completo. E o *console* não acuse como `null`(Isso quer dizer que os elementos predestinados ainda não existe). O mesmo serve também para o "script" estando em arquivo externo, ficando assim - `</body><script src="script/script.js"></script></html>`.  Deixo por aqui, para que todos saibam de ante-mão como resolver. Sem mais, agradeço.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique o indicado é que seja entre as tags `<body></body>` mesmo, e se possivel em um arquivo `externo`.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique eu errei rs desculpe, o correto é usar no final antes do fechamento do `<body>` todos os `JS` devem estar ao final do mesmo.